# How to Count total Medal of Sports data from excel

Tags: asp.net, odbc

I am working on a window application in ASP.NET. To store the data I am using an Excel sheet. The Excel sheet has following fields:

- STATE
- Point

For getting I have following criteria:

- Gold  - 7 Point
- Silver- 5 Points
- Bronze- 4 Points

I want to count total number gold, silver and bronze medal obtained by each State. For this I  used following query:

```
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SportTech"].ConnectionString);
//string query = "select STATE,sum(Point) as MEDAL from [Sheet2$] Group by STATE order by sum(Point) desc";
string query = "SELECT STATE,SUM(Point) AS MEDAL,SUM(CASE WHEN Point = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GoldCount,SUM(CASE WHEN Point = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SilverCount,SUM(CASE WHEN Point = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BronzeCount FROM [Sheet2$] GROUP BY STATE ORDER BY SUM(Point) DESC";
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, con);
OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
con.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
```

But it is showing the error:

> ERROR [42000Օ] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Syntax error (missing
>   operator) in query expression 'SUM(CASE WHEN Point = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0
>   END)'.

How can I resolve this error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you could try this. I'm using OleDB instead of Odbc

```
string constring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\\statetest.xls;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\"";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring);
string query = "select STATE,sum(IIF(point = 7,1,sum(IIF(point = 5,1,sum(IIF(point =  4,1,0)))))) as PointsPerState,sum(IIF(point = 7,1,0)) as Gold, sum(IIF(point = 5,1,0)) as Silver, sum(IIF(point = 4,1,0)) as Bronce from [Sheet2$] group by STATE";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
con.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: Thanx it works for me.Sir i want total medals of each STATE also.Would you please help me

Comment: But sir it count total Points I want total medal(Gold+Silver,Bronce) of each team.How i can i do that.Thanx

Comment: I added a new total calculation for PointPerState, hopefully got the syntax right.